# Comparing strings - input X vector of structures

Tags: c++

I ask you for help. I have input - name and surname. Now I need to find person from vector of structures with the same data and I am not able to find out working solution.

```
struct person {
    string pName;
    string pSurname;
    int weight;
    int height;
};

int solve(const string & name,const string & surname){
    std::vector<people> persons;
    std::vector<people>:: iterator it;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You have not shown the important piece of code. How are you actually finding if data is part of person ?

Comment: overload the `==` operator then apply `std::find` algorithm?

Comment: std::find_if is your friend. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find